# uwp fixed position grid

Tags: xaml, uwp

There are three child grid under one parent grid.

```
<Grid>  
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Name="grid1"> </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Name="grid2"> </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="2" Name="grid3"> </Grid>
</Grid>
```

if grid2 has more data then all three grids are scrolling.
I want the Position of grid1 and grid3 should be fixed, only middle grid should scroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can , please use fixed size value for grid1 and grid3 Rows Height
You can use [Scroll Viewer  control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/scroll-controls)

```
   <Grid>  
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="grid1"> </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Name="grid2"> 
     <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
          //Content Here
     </ScrollViewer>
       </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Name="grid3"> </Grid>
   </Grid>
```

Comment: Try putting main grid in a ScrollViewer with Horizontal and Vertical ScrollMode set to Disabled.

Comment: So glad to hear that 

Answer (score 1):

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Name="grid1" Margin="10">
        <TextBlock Text="Some Data"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Name="grid2" Margin="10">
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollMode="Auto">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="Some Data "/>
                <TextBlock Text="Some Data "/>
                <TextBlock Text="Some Data "/>
                <TextBlock Text="Some Data "/>
                <TextBlock Text="Some Data "/>
                <TextBlock Text="Some Data "/>
                <TextBlock Text="Some Data "/>
                <TextBlock Text="Some Data "/>
                <TextBlock Text="Some Data "/>
                <TextBlock Text="Some Data "/>
                <TextBlock Text="Some Data "/>
                <TextBlock Text="Some Data "/>
                <TextBlock Text="Some Data "/>
                <TextBlock Text="Some Data "/>
                <TextBlock Text="Some Data "/>
                <TextBlock Text="Some Data "/>
                <TextBlock Text="Some Data "/>
                <TextBlock Text="Some Data "/>
            </StackPanel>                
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="2" Name="grid3" Margin="10">
        <TextBlock Text="Some Data"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

[image: Output]

> *You Need to set Horizontal/Vertical Scroll Mode to Auto/Enable